# How do I solve option tag?

Tags: html, css, windows, web

I was writing my code for some page, and I wanted to make 5 options in a select list. I wrote down code, but options don't want to show up on my live server.
Here's part of my code:

```
**<fieldset>
        <label for="referrence">Which option best describes your current role?
            <section id="referrence" name="referrence">
                <option selected>Select current role</option>
                <option value=" ">Student</option>
                <option value="1">Full Time Job</option>
                <option value="2">Full Time Learner</option>
                <option value="3">Prefer not to say</option>
                <option value="4">Other</option>
            </section>
        </label>
    </fieldset>**
```

Comment: You should use `<select>` instead of `<section>`.

Answer (score 2):

you can add a `<select></select>` that wraps an `<option>`, or you can read more about it here [W3school select](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_select.asp)

```html
<fieldset>
        <label for="referrence">Which option best describes your current role?
            <section id="referrence" name="referrence">
            <select>
                <option selected>Select current role</option>
                <option value=" ">Student</option>
                <option value="1">Full Time Job</option>
                <option value="2">Full Time Learner</option>
                <option value="3">Prefer not to say</option>
                <option value="4">Other</option>
              </select>
            </section>
        </label>
    </fieldset>
```